# Admitting candidates from a no-name college?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

How many times have you really seen Graduate Admissions Office of top universities in the US and the UK admitting students for Masters Program from no-name colleges in South Asia? For example, they might know the university but the college is unknown to them because there hasn't been any student of previous batches who went to that particular university?
If a student is stuck in such a case, what could he/she do to improve their chances?

Comment: Can you please clarify the statement `they might know the university but the college is unknown to them because there hasn't been any student of previous batches who went to that particular university`? What is, in your understanding, the difference between a college and a university?

Comment: In South Asia, there is usually a university that decides the curriculum, takes the last year examination of students, issues our degree and has many, many colleges under it. In those colleges, students get their teaching from not from the university. I hope the distinction is clear.

Comment: This distinction is not clear to me and I have not seen such a model.

Comment: @Thomas the Universities of London, Oxford and Cambridge all conform to this model, to a greater or lesser degree.

Comment: Funded or unfunded?  What qualifies as "top"?

Comment: @astronat Right, but there are significant differences between those examples. Oxford and Cambridge are very uniform across colleges, whereas the University of London or the University of California have very different standards across campuses.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Top 5 in their field in that particular country.

Answer (score 1):

Every student, whether they come from a well known or an obscure university has to make his or her own case for admission. While it is easier to accept that the education from a well known place is adequate it isn't impossible to evaluate the record from someplace not yet represented in the student population. Some colleges have people who will do this as a matter of course.

Perhaps one or more of your professors can help. Sometimes the web of academic personal reach in a given field is quite broad.

But the case is still yours to make. You should demonstrate in your materials that you not only have taken courses at your university, but that you have learned the essential things needed to advance further. The presumption that MIT, for example, turns out skilled students is, for the most part, justified, but it doesn't imply that NOT-MIT cannot also do so.

But you need to make your case.